# describing a language with a regular expression

Tags: regex, math

How can i write a regular expression to describe this language :
[image]

Comment: Do you know what regular expressions are for?

Comment: First off, this really isn't a suitable question for StackOverflow; where's the code? Second, how about you tell us what you've tried so far instead of simply asking us to do your assignment for you? Third: here 's a hint: how would you do it for |w| = 2? For 7?  For 12?  Can you see the pattern?

Comment: @Mark yes i know what regular expressions are for 

@Eric Yes i can see the pattern now, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following should do the job:

[0-1]{2}([0-1]{5})*

you first take 0 or 1 twice and then you add a block of five characters (0 or 1) an arbitrary number of times

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to build a regex which matches zero or more occurences of (five `[01]`s), followed by two more `[01]`s.

In other words: `([0-1]{5})*[01]{2}`